# Why should I implement Equals(type) in addition to Equals(Object)?

Tags: c#, overriding

When I need to define my own `Equals` method usually I only override `Equals(Object)` in my class.

However [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says:

> It is also recommended that in addition to implementing Equals(object), any class also implement Equals(type) for their own type, to enhance performance.

But how could it enhance performance? I can only call one of these two method, don't I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No boxing for structs, potential for direct call for all types (instead of virtual call).

```
struct MyStruct
{
  public int v;
  public override bool Equals(Object other) {}
}
```

If you don't provide explicit method that takes MyStruct than MyStruct will have to be boxed for every calls to `myFirst.Equals(myOther)`. If you do provide `Equals(MyStruct other)` than compiler will pick that method instead more generic `Equals(Object)` thus avoiding boxing for the struct.

For all types you can provide much simple implementation of `Equals(MyType)` as you already know the type. Also compiler/JIT may be able to optimize call better if method is not virtual because more specific version does not need to be virtual.